# Rounded corners of selected item in collection view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, collectionview

I have a collectionview.When I click on image,background of selected item become orange,can you help me and say,how I can make rounded corners of this orange background.I write on Android.Please,help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C28l8.png)

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to add a `Frame` outside the image and set its rounded corners and background color (make sure your icon is transparent background) .

```
<Frame HorizontalOptions="Start" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Orange" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Padding="0">
    <Image Source="heart.png" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
</Frame>
```

the effect:

[image]